# Unbind keyboard events from mat-chip?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to be able to edit content in a mat-chip.

The process is pretty straightforward in HTML:

```html
<mat-chip contenteditable="true">Editable content</mat-chip>
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyx47b)

You can properly edit the content, however you can't delete it with [DELETE] or [BACKSPACE]. However you can cut the content (with clipboard). I think this is due to how mat-chips handle keyboard events. From the [Angular Material Doc](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api#MatChip), it indicates on the 'remove' method:

> Allows for programmatic removal of the chip. Called by the MatChipList when 
>   the DELETE or BACKSPACE keys are pressed."

So is there a way to unbind these events from the mat-chip, so that I can edit the content using these keys? I don't intend to make chips deletable via keyboard anyway.

I tried using [removable]="false" but it didn't do anything (see stackblitz)

I thought that maybe I could disable all keyboard interaction, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do so in the section on [keyboard interaction](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#keyboard-interaction).

Answer (score 4):

You can intercept the bubbling key event by add a keypress-handler in your mat-chip-content.

Your Template:

```
<mat-chip>
   <div class="input-wrapper" (keypress)="onMatChipKeyPress($event)">
      <input placeholder="Here you type in some content and press backspace or other keys">
   </div>
</mat-chip>
```

Your Javascript / Typescript:

```
onMatChipKeyPress(event) {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

Comment: I had to use (keydown) as (keypress) still blocked the input from backspace and space keys.

Comment: Works  `stopPropagation` is sufficient enough 

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-chip #chip (focus)="chip.blur()">
    example data 
    <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
```

Though its late but wanted to keep a simpler way to solve this which is on element focus we instant blur it, and this will not affect any of its functionality which is pre defined by angular material...

Comment: Not working here...